# Is there a cross browser way to make an image shrink to fit?

Tags: html, css

Apologies if this is obvious, I'm no CSS expert.

When you drop an image directly onto a web browser on any browser, they all implement some sort of "shrink to fit" functionality. Example is this video which shows shrink to fit in action on Firefox:

http://youtu.be/1LW-eByYXik

I want to implement what is shown in the video in my application and have it work cross browser to the greatest extent practical.

Is there a way to do this? Various documents on the web cover some sort of discussion about shrink to fit but none seem to discuss how to implement this for an image across browsers in a consistent manner.

I've looked at the code on the browser when an image has been dropped on and they all seem to take a different approach.

@slaks I have tried your suggestion just then on Chrome and it did not work. Here's the code I tried:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<style>

 img {
    width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%
max-height: 100%
    }
</style>

<img src="whn-data/image.png">

</body>
</html>
</head>
```

Comment: how are you delivering the image? background image? raw image? is it in a container? relevant markup please.

Comment: @SLaks' version works perfectly.

Comment: @godisgood when you says slaks version works perfectly - are saying the codee I put in my question above - which is slaks code - works perfectly?  I tried it in Chrome and it did not replicate what is in the video.

Comment: Check my answer.  I edited Slaks code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work:

```
 img {
            margin: auto;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            max-height:100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to3y20w3/1/)

Margin: auto is added to keep the image centered (both horizontal and vertical).

The max-height and max-width limit the image from going bigger than the screen.

**BUT this technique has a disadvantage:** the default size of your image has to be bigger than the height/width of the browser window or container it is in. If it is not margins will appear on all sides to keep the image's default dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `background-size: contain`.
(assuming that the image is a `background-image`)

For an `<img>` tag, use

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%
max-height: 100%
```

Comment: I'm wanting to do a foreground image.

Comment: Do you mean an `<img>` tag?

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. I've updated my question with the outcome of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what browsers implement in those cases is the property zooom.

Comment: Looking at the code on any browser when dropping an image on, they all seem to take a different approach. I had assumed they were doing something hard coded into the browser and not available as ordinary HTML because it doesn't seem possible to do in a normal web page.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT.  Sorry it took me a while.  This is actually pretty obvious.

Use this:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {  
    height: 100%;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/wcuw2cvr/2/)

Comment: How can I make this answer favorite so I can find it easily when I need it?

Comment: Click the star symbol. @ADASein.  Glad my answer helped you!